# What I have to do if stream in StreamBuilder return null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use websocket with this package [websocket](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) and everything is fine until I realize that if the channel cannot connect with server in the first time, stream will be null and I get this error:

> The getter 'stream' was called on null

I make channel as an Singleton class so I can call close or add everywhere I want in my app:

```
class WebSocket {
  static IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  static init() async {
    try {
      String macAddress = await getMacAddress();
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://172.16.0.39:8001/ws/fsmart-door/$macAddress");
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I call Websocket.init() in the main so that the channel will be ready for stream but if IOWebSocketChannel.connect cannot connect, the app will be stuck too.

This is my StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream:  WebSocket.channel.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {

    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
      child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
    );
 },
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the channel cannot connect? Just show an error, try to reconnect automatically or add a button to try to reconnect?

Comment: I want to reconnect automatically

Answer (score 2):

The thing is when the connection fails, `channel` is `null` so you can't do `channel.stream` and the `StreamBuilder` can't have a `Stream`. So, one approach you could take is to have a `Stream` in the `WebSocket` that handles the retries and when the `channel` is ready, pass the data that comes from `channel.stream` to the `WebSocket` `Stream`.

This is how could be the `WebSocket`:

```
class WebSocket {
  static WebSocket _instance;
  final _streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
  IOWebSocketChannel channel;

  static WebSocket get instance {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = WebSocket();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  Stream get channelStream => _streamController.stream;

  Future init(int retries) async {
    if (channel == null) {
      await _tryToConnect(retries);
      if (channel != null) {
        _streamController.sink.add(null);
        channel.stream.listen((value) {
          _streamController.sink.add(value);
        });
      } else {
        _streamController.sink.addError("Could not connect");
      }
    }
  }

  Future _tryToConnect(int retries) async {
    if (channel == null) {
      try {
        String macAddress = await getMacAddress();
        // This is to throw exception if it can't connect (https://github.com/dart-lang/web_socket_channel/issues/38#issuecomment-450383558)
        final socket = await WebSocket.connect(
                "ws://172.16.0.39:8001/ws/fsmart-door/$macAddress")
            .timeout(_webSocketConnectionTimeout);
        channel = IOWebSocketChannel(socket);
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
      if (channel == null && retries > 0) {
        _streamController.sink.addError("Retries left: ${retries - 1}");
        await _tryToConnect(retries - 1);
      }
    }
  }

  void close() => _streamController.close();
}
```

And this would be the `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: WebSocket.instance.channelStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return Text('Loading...');
  },
)
```

---

If you want to make a quick test of this solution, replace the two lines in the `try` `catch`, for this:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
if (retries == 2) channel = IOWebSocketChannel();
```

Use this `IOWebSocketChannel`

```
class IOWebSocketChannel {
  var _streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  IOWebSocketChannel() {
    init();
  }

  Stream get stream => _streamController.stream;

  Future init() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    _streamController.sink.add("1");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    _streamController.sink.add("2");
  }

  void close() => _streamController.close();
}
```

And use this example in a `StatefulWidget`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WebSocket.instance.init(5);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: WebSocket.instance.channelStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return Text('Loading...');
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried to check null for channel but the problem is IOWebSocketChannel.connect() still return IOWebSocketChannel even if it can't connect so I can't check it to call reconnect channel. However, your implement is great. I have solved my problem although it's kinda not flexible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm checking if the channel variable of the WebSocket is null, not the channel returned by connect(). I suppose that if it can't connect it throws an exception so channel won't be assigned

Comment: Even if it doesn't throws an exception, then you could check if channel == null || !channel.isConnected() or whatever method you have to know if it's connected

Comment: In tryToConnect, channel is assigned from connect, so it cannot recall to reconnect since it cannot be null, it not throw exception too, i have tried it. Sorry I can't accept your answear, upvote for great implement. Thanks you

Comment: No problem, I just want to understand how that works. If connect returns an object but is not connected, how do you know is not connected?

Comment: I just check server connection with api then if I catch an exception from api, I will reconnect websocket again util I can. it's not good but it's work.

Comment: It seems that is a known issue the handling of the connect: https://github.com/dart-lang/web_socket_channel/issues/38#issuecomment-450383558. I added the workaround to my answer in case someone wants to use this solution.